# Expo error: Compiling JS failed: unrecognized character '@'

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got the answer after some luck search in Google, so I decided to share this here for a more easier to find solution

After `expo start`, Android emulator shows error message `Compiling JS failed: XX:XX: unrecognized character '@'`

For any JS parsing problems, you can always check the error position to see what's going by opening your browser directly at bundle.

For default host and port open:
http://127.0.0.1:8081/

Inside JSON object, there will be an URL at `$.launchAsset.url` which you can use to access bundled JS file

Answer (score 0):

Character '@' is most likely related to an annotation. In my case, this was caused by InversifyJS and is related to how babel is handling annotation transformation

Possible solutions:

1. Configure babel transformer, as [this comment](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1007#issuecomment-490835213) suggests
2. Use typescript shorthand constructor syntax, as [this comment](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1113#issuecomment-531819266) suggests

Related inversify github issues:

- [#1113](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1113)
- [#1007](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1007)
- [#1050](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1050)